# Spring Boot + Jackson >= 2.7.x fail with @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following class:

```
public class Person {

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_WRITE)
    private String name;

    // constructors and getters/setters are omitted

}
```

When I use it like this:

```
@RestController
public class PersonEndpoint {

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Person savePerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        System.out.println(person);
        return person;
    }

}
```

Jackson fails when deserializing the object:

`WARN MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.mycompany.myapp.model.Person]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'name' (in class com.mycompany.myapp.model.Person)`

There is no such problem when changing Jackson's version to 2.6.7.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried the same example and it's working fine. What Jackson libs have you added as dependencies? Why don't you try a newer one, like 2.8.4 ?

Comment: I tried it too (2.8.4 is the default one for Spring Boot 1.4.2) and it doesn't work.

Comment: It does look more like a dependency problem than a bug. Could you please update your post with your Gradle/Maven depedencies list?